# org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Method Not Allowed [405]

Tags: spring, web-services, exchangewebservices, spring-ws

I am trying to invoke ews webservice using the spring webservices.

But I am getting `org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Method Not Allowed [405]`

When I try to invoke any method.

Any idea what the issue may be?

Comment: Please post some more code and what goes wrong. There is too little information here. Show some code, configuration and what are you calling?

Comment: I found out the reason for this issue, i was using wsdl URL instead of the Exchange.aspx one.

Answer (score 1):

I Got Same Problem , while  working  with **Spring With Services**

To day I resolve this one

**Solution**

If You Run Server Code And client code with different portnumbers in same system

we will get the **WebServiceTransportException**

To resolve this one

Deploy you client and servcer code into tomcat server  and try to run It

Both Client And Server Must be Run With Same Port Number , If You write both client and server in one machine  Other Wise You Will Get WebServiceTransportException

by

**Patnaidu**

Answer (score 1):

In my applicationContext.xml there is a:

```
"< property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/person"/>"
```

and i changed it into :

```
 "< property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/Person/services" />"
```

I discovered by going into `soupUI` and seeing that there works but on that url so i changed it.